# SharePoint Online - Enable Site Feature by Default

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2013, office365

I've had a search on here, and also via Google, but can't seem to see anything SPOnline specific, so ended up here ;)

Is there a way that I can enable a site feature by default in SharePoint Online, i.e. Office 365 Enterprise.

I'm not after any specifics (although that would be awesome), but just someone to say "yes, you can do it via powershell check this cmdlet out" would suffice.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Googling "Feature Stapling SharePoint Online" and the prospect looks dismal:
http://sharepointrepairjoint.blogspot.com/2012/03/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint-online.html

Comment: Good find, is that what the term is for what i am asking? "Feature Stapling" ? Would never have guessed that :D

Comment: "Feature Stapling" is where you designate that a feature is always activated when a given type of site is created.

I assume that's what you're after.